# ListView only one element shown with height = "wrap_content"

Tags: android, listview, layout, height

On my fragment layout I have a Nested Scroll view with two relative layout inside, top and bottom, on the bottom I have a listview with about twenty elements, but if I set the height of the listview with wrap_content, only one line is shown, whereas if I set the height to 1000dp, for example, all the lines are shown, I wouldn't want to fix the height in a static way but I'd rather use wrap_content, what can I do?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nested_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/top">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        //some button and text view
    </RelativeLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>

  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_below="@id/top">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scores"
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: where is your adapter means listview items xml file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below Utility method to set the height of your `ListView` based on child count.

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView myListView) {
        ListAdapter adapter = myListView.getAdapter(); 
        if (myListView != null) {
           int totalHeight = 0;
           for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
              View item= adapter.getView(i, null, myListView);
              item.measure(0, 0);
              totalHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
           }

           ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
           params.height = totalHeight + (myListView.getDividerHeight() * (adapter.getCount() - 1));
           myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }          
    }
```

Comment: Almost work, but it didn't completly. The calculations were always bigger than it should, and the results always showed some blank space at the end. My solution was actually using this external library (https://github.com/paolorotolo/ExpandableHeightListView) as suggested by @Αλέξανδρος Τσιχουρίδης on a comment below

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this one [Expandable Height List View](https://github.com/paolorotolo/ExpandableHeightListView).

I personally use this one: [Exapandable Height GridView](https://gist.github.com/bomeekim/9bb461736f506ec7626c) and is the same philosophy with the [Expandable Height List View](https://github.com/paolorotolo/ExpandableHeightListView).

Answer (score 0):

1.Remove the NestedScrollView 
2. add this to the android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" like this

```
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scores"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Please explain to the OP what _this will do_.

Comment: i need all the fragment to scroll not only the list view

Answer (score 0):

Man, this is one kind of RelativeLayout Blitzkrieg. But if it is what you need to fit your feature, maybe you should try to set the NestedScrollView to fill its viewport.

android:fillViewport="true"

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nested_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

Tried this with a "deblitzkrieged" version of what you posted and it worked, maybe it also works 4 you.

UPDATE:
You are right, the upper approach would leave you with a non scrollable fragment.

I also set `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` on the ListView and instantly forgot about it.
If someone is still interested in a code sample, see the sample below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nested_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:id="@+id/top">
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Foo Bar"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:id="@+id/bottom"
                android:layout_below="@id/top">
            <ListView
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/scores">
            </ListView>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: this does not allow the fragment to scroll, meybe because the list elements shown are as many as you can enter from where the listview begins to where the screen ends. If there were more elements than these they are not shown