# My list size is all the screen and can't see buttons below or scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, kotlin, android-fragments

I have tried everything, from nested scroll view, to just scrollviews to wrap my whole view.

The thing is that my list is too big and I cant see the buttons below it, so I want to be able to scroll my list untill the end and then show up my buttons on the bottom

if the list is small all buttons are shown , but when its too large I cant

I dont know if I have implemented nested scrolling right or not but here is the code I have that currently does not display my buttons on scroll of big list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.attendance.RecordAttendanceFragment">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/Toolbar"
        app:contentInsetStart="0sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_back"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_24" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="43dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo"
                    tools:text="My idea pool" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/empty_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_empty_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            tools:text="test" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/meeting"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/attendence_groups_selected_view">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Meeting title"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardMeetingtitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/ext_group_meeting_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:hint="Group meeting"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/attendance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Attendees"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/attendance_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_save_attendance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_round_blue"
        android:text="Record attendance"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_select_all"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_round_white"
        android:text="Select all"
        android:textColor="@color/blueButtons" />

</LinearLayout>
```

These last two buttons does not show if the list is too large, they are below my screen and when I scroll to the bottom of the list I can't see them

Answer (score 1):

As **list views can be infinitely large**, they don't really behave well when you set their heights to wrap content. You should instead **fix it's height** to some value either a concrete value or using gravity or something like that, and then the buttons should be at the bottom of the screen. Of course, this means that the buttons will always be visible under the `ListView`, which may not be what you're trying to achieve. I assume you want to have the buttons appear when you scroll all the way to the bottom of the list view.

For the latter there are some possible solutions:

- [Set the height of your list view base on the child count](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56818565/5601663), and then you'll be able to put it inside a scroll view and it will work as expected. <-- I have not tried this solution myself but can work, but feels a bit hacky.
- Use the buttons as a view type inside your adapter, and put them inside the list view directly. <-- I would prefer this way personally.
- Don't use list views, rather insert your list items inside a vertical linear layout, and have the parent layout be a ScrollView. <-- This again solves the problem, of having a well-defined height, as LinearLayout's have well defined heights, they can be scrolled. If your list is small I think this can be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add button and list in another view, for example, add in RelativeLayout and like this

------>

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/attendance_list"
    android:layout_above="@id/btn_save_attendance"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

<Button
    android:background="@drawable/button_round_blue"
    android:id="@+id/btn_save_attendance"
    android:layout_above="@id/btn_select_all"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="Record attendance"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<Button
    android:background="@drawable/button_round_white"
    android:id="@+id/btn_select_all"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="Select all"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

using in RelativeLayout, the button will be always on top whether the list is larger or not

Answer (score 0):

Convert your layout to a file like below

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
                ......
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView     
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appBarLayout" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

create a adapter file  with footer and list items :

```
class Adaptor(var list: ArrayList<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

companion object {
    const val FooterType = 1
    const val ListType = 0
}

private var layoutInflater: LayoutInflater? = null
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    if (layoutInflater == null) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    }
    return if (viewType == FormAdapter.FooterType) {
        val binding: FooterBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater!!, R.layout.footer, parent, false)//footer view = 2 buttons
        ViewHolderFooter(binding)

    } else {
        val binding: ListItemsBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater!!, R.layout.list_items, parent, false)//cardView for your list items(in XML file)
        ListViewHolder(binding)
    }

}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int { 
    return if (position == list.size()-1)
        FooterType
    else
        ListType

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list.size + 1
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
}

class ViewHolderFooter(var binding: FooterBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {


}
....
```

so you can have two buttons at the end of the layout without the need to scrolling to the end and even your list becomes too big you can see the buttons.